# How or why this is good for me

Tags: sentence-choice

I don't understand how this is good for me.

I don't understand why this is good for me.

Do they mean the same? If not what's the difference? Or maybe nuance? What context would one use them respectively and what would the answers be. Thanks.

Comment: In many contexts, ***how*** and ***why*** are more or less equivalent. But in principle there's a difference between them. *I know **how** I should do it* means I know the ***method of*** doing it, whereas *I know **why** I should do it* means I know the ***reason for*** doing it. You can figure out for yourself whether and to what extent that same difference might apply to your specific example context.

Comment: ...for example, your first version might invite a doctor to start telling you all sorts of low-level details about ***how*** the medicine he's just prescribed you actually ***works*** inside your body. But for the second version he might just say something like *It's good for you **because** it will cure your disease*.